# Comparison class constructor parameter between Typescript and Javascript ES6, ES.NEXT

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, oop, ecmascript-6

I've been studying TypeScript as the requirement for Angular2/5 and I encountered some doubts.
A couple months ago I also upgraded my knowledge of JS ES6 and so on.
I'm quite sure that I'm not in wrong but for a full understanding of TS I'll ask you anyway.

This is the code that you can find here:

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties

```
{
    class Octopus {
       readonly numberOfLegs: number = 8;
       constructor(readonly classAttr: string) { ... } // name attribute 
    }
    console.log( (new Octopus('spicylemoned')).classAttr ); // It works
}
```

Is there a way in recent JS updates to define attributes inside class' constructor in vanilla like so in TS? (w/o implicitly assigning it through `this` instance)

```
{
    class Test{
        constructor({ passedVar : classAttr } ) { ... };
    };
    console.log( (new Test({ passedVar : 'sweety' })).classAttr ); 
    //it doesnt work
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this in JavaScript. You have to do it in the constructor with `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JS there isn't any similar syntax. The easiest way to do this is to use `Object.assign()`:

```js
class Test {
  constructor({ passedVar }) {
    Object.assign(this, { classAttr: passedVar });
  }
}

console.log(new Test({ passedVar: 'sweety' }).classAttr);
```

This way is better if you have many attributes; if there's only one, you can just assign in to `this`: `this.classAttr = passedVar`.

Comment: Even simpler would be to match the input parameter with the property name: `constructor ({ classAttr } = {}) { Object.assign(this, { classAttr }); }` The `= {}` allows you to call the constructor with no arguments to initialize everything to `undefined` by default.

Comment: I know you answered the question as asked. That note was for OP. I'm sure you know how destructuring and default parameters work already ;)

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a very contrived way of passing an object initializer to a class using a custom `Proxy`. It may seem verbose, but the `Proxy` can be re-used for as many class definitions as you want:

```js
// mem initializer list
const list = (() => {
  let props = new WeakMap()

  // this: class instance
  // o: initializer object
  function initialize(o = {}) {
    if (props.has(this)) {
      return this[props.get(this)] = o;
    }

    return new Proxy(o, {
      get: (o, p) => (props.set(this, p), this[p] = o[p])
    });
  }

  // .call.bind() allows initialize(this, o)
  // to pass a context and one argument
  // instead of two arguments
  return initialize.call.bind(initialize);
})();

// example usage
class Test {
  constructor (o, { classAttr = list(this, 'foo'), undefinedParameter = list(this, 'bar') } = list(this, o)) {
    /* ... */
  }
}

console.log(new Test({ classAttr: 'sweety', excessParameter: 'oops' }));
console.log(new Test());
```

Notice that `undefinedParameter` is always initialized with its default value `'bar'`, while the `excessParameter` is never added to the class instance.

**Note:** this is by no means a performant solution. It is a pure gimmick, but demonstrates that it is possible to somewhat implicitly initialize a class instance.

A downside to using this approach is that there is no way to intercept default parameters like

```
{ classAttr = 'defaultValue' }
```

so instead you have to use the somewhat unsavory syntax

```
{ classAttr = list(this, 'defaultValue') }
```

in order to provide default parameters.

If you are extending another class, you must initialize the instance with a `Proxy` returned by `list(super(), o)`:

```js
const list = (() => {
  let props = new WeakMap()

  function initialize(o = {}) {
    if (props.has(this)) {
      return this[props.get(this)] = o;
    }

    return new Proxy(o, {
      get: (o, p) => (props.set(this, p), this[p] = o[p])
    });
  }

  return initialize.call.bind(initialize);
})();

// example usage
class Test extends Object {
  constructor (o, { classAttr = list(this, 'foo'), undefinedParameter = list(this, 'bar') } = list(super(), o)) {
    /* ... */
  }
}

console.log(new Test({ classAttr: 'sweety', excessParameter: 'oops' }));
console.log(new Test());
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an ES6 class forbids the assignment of properties directly on a prototype object within the class definition.

You are allowed to use a getter to achieve the same effect. Only defining a getter will also make it readonly.

However, there is no implicit syntax within vanilla javascript to handle typechecks, meaning this must be done manually using `typeof <variable> === '<primitiveType>'` or `<variable> instanceof <Class>` within the function.

Using the Octopus class this will result in the following:

```
class Octopus{
    constructor(classAttr){
        if (typeof classAttr !== 'string' && typeof classAttr !== 'object') { 
            throw new TypeError('classAttr is neither a string nor an object');
        }
        if (typeof classAttr === 'object') {
            Object.assign(this,classAttr);
        }
        else {
            this.classAttr = classAttr;
        }
    }

    //readonly, because there is no setter
    get numberOfLegs(){
        return 8;
    }
}

let octopus = new Octopus('bigEyed');
console.log(octopus.numberOfLegs);     // 8
console.log(octopus.classAttr);        // bigEyed
```